# Oracle query performance issue on view

Tags: oracle, performance, view

I am facing some performance issue for below ORACLE query:

select fms.*,v.ph_typ_strng_id,v.ph_typ
  from fct_miscdata fms -- (having 10 columns)
 cross join lkp_lang LL -- (having 3 columns with 2 rows. we can't remove this cross join)
  left outer join vw_dim_ph_typ v ON v.LANG_COD = LL.LANG_COD  -- (PH_TYP_STRNG_ID, PH_TYP, Lang)
 where v.lang_cod != '00_00' and fms.s_key = 0  and fms.t_key = 0 
   and v.ph_typ_strng_id = case
    when exists (select 'x'
                  from vw_dim_excp_typ_inter m -- (misc_typSkey,src,tnt, misc_typId) -- only 3 miscTypeId : 0,98,99
                 where fms.in_misc_typ_skey = m.misc_typ_skey
                   and m.s_key = fms.s_key
                   and m.t_key = fms.t_key) then
           case
              when not exists (select 'x'
                      from vw_dim_excp_typ_inter m
                     where fms.out_misc_typ_skey = m.misc_typ_skey
                       and m.s_key = fms.s_key
                       and m.t_key = fms.t_key) then
               0006
           end
          else 0004
       end;

==> Its a materialized view in oracle which is refreshing in a Oracle procedure. Whenever I am trying to run this procedure, its taking long hours approx(1 hr) for run. Indexes are already created on tables.

--> Due to last code of lines CASE statement, its taking so much time to run. If I comment this part it'll run in few minutes. No. of records are 90772580.

--> Is there any alternate solution for this query to improve performance.
    Please suggest how can I optimize/improve this query performance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried `EXPLAIN PLAN` on your query already? it should give you some insight.

Comment: The query you posted is syntactically incorrect. There is a double 
and and, and there is an and missing before the case statement. Please post the correct query.

Comment: This one is syntactically incorrect: `and fms.t_key = 0 v.ph_typ_strng_id = case` - provide the working query.

Comment: I have updated the query, please have a look.